# Spring security default login form unable to load CSS files (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)

Tags: java, css, spring-boot, spring-security, authentication

It looks like Spring Security's default login page uses bootstrap.min.css and signin.css to style itself.  The login page displays correctly when running the project from Eclipse but not when running from the Spring Boot fat jar.  The errors are :

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT bootstrap.min.css
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT signin.css
```

These files are managed by Spring Security and I do not know where they are even stored.  Like I said the login page works perfectly when running from Eclipse and the rest of the app works perfectly in both environment (thymeleaf templates using bootstrap with Spring MVC backend controllers, secured by Spring Security).

What could be causing these errors?

Comment: did you authorize requests to those elements?

Comment: What version of Spring Security do you use?

Comment: Do you use any firewall, which doesn't allow you to download the files from internet?

Comment: Indeed, the environment i'm deploying on does not have access to the internet.  Is there a way to have Spring Security load these stylesheets locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use matchers against your static resources to be served ?

**In case of local resources in other location than default (not recomended)**

```
http
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/lib/bootstrap/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/img/**",
                "/js/**").permitAll();
```

**In case of webjars**

```
http
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll();
```

Did you even wanted to protect serving those resources with a login constraints? On what purpose?

**In case of static resources in the default known directoriers :**

> While this may not be a new revelation to those of you that have been
>   following Spring Boot since the SpringOne announcement, there is one
>   detail for which you may not be aware. Spring Boot will automatically
>   add static web resources located within any of the following
>   directories:
>
> ```
> /META-INF/resources/
> /resources/
> /static/
> /public/
> ```

If you add those files in one of these defaut location of the project structure then no need to authorize requests to them.

See this [article](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) for further details

**NB** : When using default page of spring you can't have a standalone environment and an internet access is mandatory to laod resources. You have to implement you custom [login page](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/).

```
    http
       .formLogin()
       .loginPage("/login")
       .permitAll();
```

Don't forget to chain your spring security rules if needed

Comment: Those files are not under my control, they seem to be included into Spring Security somehow.  Therefore, I cannot authorize requests to them.  Plus, I do not have this issue when running from Eclipse, only when running the jar.

Comment: So when i just run the project from Eclipse everything works fine, the login page has style and doesn't take 30 seconds to reload.  When i deploy the jar file resulting from the build process in production and run it from a batch file (java -jar), i get this issue where it's complaining it can't find CSS files that i've never seen before.  Those are not my CSS files, they are somehow bundled with Spring Security therefore I cannot explicitly authorize them since they don't really have a location.

Comment: It depends on the jar dependencies ? You seem to use bootstrap at least to render your pages in href somewhere: isn't?

Comment: The jar dependencies are the same as when i run it from the IDE.  I do use bootstrap in my views but those work perfectly.  Spring Security's default login page seems to point to bootstrap.min.css and signin.css which it provides itself somehow and that is what doesn't work when running from the jar.  The login page works as in the functionality is there but it's displayed in unstyled HTML and takes 30 seconds to load.

Comment: When using eclispe ide the classpath state is abstracted to you. It is different when running in a "standalone" environment.Be sides, i don't see how you use those static resources unless you add them to your resources folder or used webjars dependances in your page? Please give mor details about your code and project structure in the question

Comment: The fact that the whole app works perfectly besides this seems to indicate that Spring Security's "bundling" of these 2 CSS files is somehow broken when running the jar on its own.  I have absolutely no control over these CSS files and i didn't even know they existed before trying to deploy the jar to my staging server.  My project is dependent on webjar indeed but everything works besides the default Spring Security login page.

Comment: @HassamAbdelillah Your answer and your comments are not really helpful. If you would know Spring Boot you would know what *running a jar* means. If you would understand HTML, you wouldn't say *i don't see how you use those static resources unless you add them to your resources folder* It is just an URL in a HTML file. And if you would know Spring Security, you wouldn't say *Please give mor details about your code and project structure in the question* Martin already wrote it, it is part of Spring Security not of his own code.

Comment: static resources unless you add them to your resources folder or in cases of webjars. In cases of webjars his has the obligation to permits those let pass those requests...Don't be easy to judge...

Comment: @HassamAbdelillah That's only two ways, the URL is `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/signin/signin.css`

Comment: @Martin said that his uses webjars in his project i think that's why

Comment: @HassamAbdelillah Perhaps, you are right, but why and how could he fix it? Why should it be possible to load `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/signin/signin.css` within the IDE and not within a jar?

Comment: My IDE is run from my machine which has access to internet.  My staging server is in a super locked down environment that does not have access to internet.  Is there a way for these files to be served locally?

Comment: If it is in a standalone environment, you are obliged to have them as local resources as in the answer.

Comment: so i can just download them and put them in my resources folder?

Comment: i put a copy of the signin.css file in the CSS folder inside my static folder but when looking at the sources tab in chrome it's still taking it from the web.  Mind you, this is on my dev machine with access to internet so it may default back to my local resources when running the jar from my staging machine.  I will try.

Comment: Did you change the html href location to the css?

Comment: again, this is Spring Security's default login page.  I have absolutely no control over this page.  The only way i was able to confirm it was indeed using online CSS files was with the sources tab in chrome.

Comment: Really with what you provided as info we can't help you more. I advise you to give more details about you webpages and project structure :)

Comment: I honestly don't think my project structure makes a difference here.  My question boils down to this : how do you make Spring Security use local CSS files instead of the online ones?  I have placed both files it's complaining about in my static folder and it's still timing out looking for them on the internet on my staging machine.

Comment: I see the problem better now. You are using the default login page of Spring and therefore, Spring need internet access to load all resources needed to construct this page. see edit

Comment: I was hoping there was another way, i kinda like the simplistic look of the default login page but I was starting to consider making my own and avoiding this issue altogether.

Comment: In a philosophy of a standalone environment you should not consider a solution permitting a external third party load resources...I thing having you own login page is a best fit

Comment: @Martin did the answer fits to you? if so, please accept to benefit others